# Using putty to scp from windows to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty, scp

I'm trying to test some C code that I'm writing. The only issue is that the code needs to be executed on a remote machine. 
My laptop is pretty old, and there is no driver for my wireless card available for Ubuntu, so booting into Linux to circumvent this problem isn't an option. 
Here's my question:

I'm using putty to SSH into the remote machine, and I'm writing my code on Notepad++.
The location of my file is:
     `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\WMU\5260\A2.c`

My problem is that when I use the command `scp C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\WMU\5260\A2.c ~`
I get the error `could not resolve hostname C:. Name or service not known".`

I've also tried `scp Users\Admin\Desktop\WMU\5260\A2.c ~` which gives me the error `Cannot stat 'Users\Admin\Desktop\WMU\5260\A2.c': no such file or directory`

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to tell `scp` where to send the file. In your command that is not working:

```
scp C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\WMU\5260\A2.c ~
```

You have not mentioned a remote server. `scp` uses `:` to delimit the host and path, so it thinks you have asked it to download a file at the path `\Users\Admin\Desktop\WMU\5260\A2.c` from the host `C` to your local home directory.

The correct upload command, based on your comments, should be something like:

```
C:\> pscp C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\WMU\5260\A2.c ckg8221@thor.cs.wmich.edu:
```

If you are running the command from your home directory, you can use a relative path:

```
C:\Users\Admin> pscp Desktop\WMU\5260\A2.c ckg8221@thor.cs.wmich.edu:
```

You can also mention the directory where you want to this folder to be downloaded to at the remote server. i.e by just adding a path to the folder as below:

```
C:/> pscp C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\WMU\5260\A2.c ckg8221@thor.cs.wmich.edu:/home/path_to_the_folder/
```

Comment: Can you clarify that this is partially an extension of Putty, and may needed to be added to PATH if you dont switch to the putty dir?  I was confused where pscp comes from, it was almost as if it was insinuated that its already on Dos, which threw me way off.   Here's a link that describes that PSCP is a putty extension that you have and may need to add it to your PATH, etc.. https://it.cornell.edu/managed-servers/transfer-files-using-putty

Answer (score 30):

You can use [PSCP](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html) to copy files from Windows to Linux.

1. Download PSCP from putty.org
2. Open cmd in the directory with pscp.exe file
3. Type command `pscp source_file user@host:destination_file`

   - Ex.
     `pscp sample.txt myuser@myhost.com:/mydata/sample.txt`

[Reference](https://it.cornell.edu/managed-servers/transfer-files-using-putty)

Comment: putty may already have came with it, depending on the version you installed, it may just not be in the path.  see link on my comment on @nobody answer.

Answer (score 20):

Use `scp priv_key.pem source user@host:target` if you need to connect using a private key.

or if using pscp then use `pscp -i priv_key.ppk source user@host:target`